# How To Add External Dependency in Guidewire

Tags: docusignapi, guidewire, gosu

I need an external library to be used in Guidewire. Below is the name of the library in which I am interested which is available on the maven repository.

I am not sure how to add an external java library inside ClaimCenter or PolicyCenter. Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

*https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.docusign/docusign-esign-java*

Answer (score 0):

You can add external .jar files inside jdk installation directory.
Ex: jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\docusign.jar.

Local machine - after adding the jar, Check in IDE: File->ProjectStructure->SDKs->Classpath. If added jar is not present, add it manually by '+'.

Higher env -> add the jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\docusign.jar in same jdk dir, which tomcat is using.

Comment: Thanks, bro, BTW I have resolved the issue. I followed the Guidewire documentation in which it was written that I had to drop the jar files at the right location. The location was "ClaimCenter/modules/configuration/plugins/PLUGIN_DIR/lib". BTW DocuSign jars are not in good condition on the maven repo. So I have dropped the underlying jars (bouncy castle and OAuth) in ClaimCenter and have written my own custom code. They are working fine.